# react masking with two decimals required

Tags: javascript, reactjs, decimal, mask, masking

I am using the react masking: https://github.com/sanniassin/react-input-mask, or actually https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-masking.
I´d like to create a mask that always returns '9.99' or '99.99'.
I can´t figure out how to do that.

examples:

- input '5' output '5.00' (or '05.00')
- input '12' output '12.00'
- input '3.4' output '3.40' (or '03.40')
- input '8.47' output '8.47' (or'08.47')
- input '11.35' output '11.35'

I tried with mask='9.99' and maskCharacter="0" 
but this messes up typing.

Has someone tips or even made this before?
All help is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you need to use `.toFixed(2)`.

Comment: i think mask input will not return the input value in that format, it will just force the user to provide the input in that format..